# HttpClient: кросс-доменные запросы

Tags: php, angular2, cookie, cors, angular5

### API

Есть сервис аутентификации, разработанный на PHP и развернутый на хостинге `XX.XX.XX.XX`, командой backend. И у этого сервиса есть API

```
POST: http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8081/login

body {
username
password
}
```

возвращающий cookie `PHPSESSID`.

---

### ЗАПРОС С ПОМОЩЬЮ REST-CLIENT (расширение chrome)

Если с помощью `Rest Client` сделать этот запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то как видите, запрос проходит и необходимый cookie возвращается.

---

### ЗАПРОС С ПОМОЩЬЮ HttpClient

Теперь если выполнить этот запрос из приложения-Angular, развернутого *естественно* на `localhost:4200` с помощью кода:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  readonly endpoint = 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8081/login';

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  post(userName: string, password: string) {
    console.log('AuthService.post has been executed!');    

    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', 'name')
      .set('password', 'pass');

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()      
      .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    const options = {
      headers: headers      
    };

    return this.httpClient.post(this.endpoint, body, options);
  }
}
```

то в консоль отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### ВОПРОС

Как правильно настроить HttpClient для выполнения этого кросс-запроса. Backend-разработчики уверены, что у сервиса CORS-настройки правильно настроены, но если этого не так, то на какие настройки обратить их внимание?

Comment: Так вам же сообщает браузер, что заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin нет. И в ответе на запрос из расширения он отсутствует. Вероятно бэкенд-разработчики что-то путают. Возможно заголовок отдаётся в ручке, на которую идёт редирект, а нужно и в ответе с перенаправлением тоже.

Comment: Не знаю как в php, но в ASP.NET надо разрешать cors на бекенде.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Вы имеете ввиду что в этом заголовке сервер должен вернуть `localhost`?

Comment: @adamshakhabov да. Или *.

Comment: @adamshakhabov и протокол и порт (если не *) не забывайте